# Space on the bottom of a divbox

Tags: html, css, ejs

Could someone tell me how I could have some empty space on the bottom of my divbox so that the text does not touch the borders?

[https://i.imgur.com/PRd1yNg.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zdef.jpg)

My HTML code:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="outsideRev">
        <div class="reviews">
            <% if (restaurant.reviews.length > 0) { %>
            <hr>
            <% for (let review of restaurant.reviews) { %>
            <p><%= review.review %></p>
            <p><%= review.title %> - <%= review.user.username %></p>
            <hr>
            <% } %>
            <% } else { %>
            <p>No reviews! Be the first one to post a review.</p>
            <% } %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.main .outsideRev {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border: 1px black solid;
    height: 35vh;
    width: 80%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.main .outsideRev .reviews {
    padding: 40px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: try adding a bottom margin to .outsideRev class

Answer (score 0):

This is how I will manage.

1. Add a wrapper div around the container `reviews`. I would give a class `"margin"` to it.

First set the display of class `outsideRev` to flexbox:

```
.outsideRev {
  display: flex;
}
```

Then I would add the following the styling to new div.

```
.margin {
overflow: hidden scroll;
/*   Makes the content scrollable and not overflow. */
  height: 90%;
/*   Given the space at top and bottom of the container. */
  margin: auto 10px;
/*   Giving a top and bottom margin by auto centering the content vertically. */
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88bHU.jpg)

Hope it helps, thank you.